# Scaling a regenerated square pattern in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: combinatorics

We have the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $\{(a,b):a>0\land b>0\}$ and we have a special arrangement of squares as shown. We scale everything by $\dfrac{1}{3}$ and obtain the arrangement of squares shown below.

[image]

Now imagine that this scaling process is gradual and continuous such that every square moves and contracts to acquire the final scaled form which is a continuous morphism $f_t([x,y]) = \frac{1}{1+2t}[x,y]:0\le t\le1\land x,y>0$. Also imagine that the squares leave continuous imprints (like tire tracks) as they travel. The question is to prove that at the end of the scaling process, the union of the tracks, the original square positions and the final square positions contains the whole of $\{(a,b):a>1\land b>1\}$ which can be thought of as the whole of the first quadrant obtained after moving the origin a unit up and then a unit right.

Comment: When you say 'every square moves and contracts', you mean the continuous morphism given on $0\leq t\leq 1$ by something like $f_t([x,y]) = \frac{1}{1+2t}[x,y]$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Precisely!